# How can I add same numbers in existing list?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

My function to generate random numbers is this:

```
public static List<int> GetRandomNumbers(int count)
{
    HashSet<int> randomNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        while(!randomNumbers.Add(random.Next(100, 999)));
    }

    return randomNumbers.ToList();
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list = GetRandomNumbers(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(list[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Ok, so, what I want to do is, for example, if the list generated is the following:

```
152 582 254 891 421
```

I want to make the list be:

```
152 152 582 582 254 254 891 891 421 421
```

Basically, each number to be added one more time after itself in the list. How can I do this? (It would be good if you include a simple way to do this considering time not a problem, and maybe a better way to save time)

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of a `HashSet` is to be unique.

Comment: @SLaks I know that... that is why I used HashSet in the function to generate numbers, because I only need unique numbers in the list later on. But I think it doesn't have to do anything with what I'm trying to do..

Comment: change the `HashSet` to a `List` and just add the random number twice

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear.

You can take a list (not a `HashSet`) with repeating elements and move every repetition to immediately follow the first occurrence like this:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(i => random.NextInt(0, 300));
return numbers.GroupBy(i => i).SelectMany(s => s).ToList();
```

You can take an existing list and make each element repeat twice like this:

```
list.SelectMany(o => Enumerable.Repeat(o, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if my English is bad or not, but the function works absolutely fine as I want it to. I am asking once I generate the 'list' variable, how can I add them there? After the generation if possible :)

Comment: @user4398763: It sounds like you want my second solution.

Comment: I tried it, but doesn't seem to work for some reason. I added it before the for loop and it doesn't seem to change anything. I don't understand what it's supposed to do either way.

Comment: That returns a new `IEnumerable<T>`.  You need to learn about LINQ.

Comment: Oh. I see. Unfortunately, I can't use LINQ for this project. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Why not? You could write a for loop to build a new list.

Comment: I see. I guess I'll have to write a for loop then, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You could change your function slightly to:

```
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static List<int> GetRandomNumbers(int count)
    {
        int value;
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        HashSet<int> randomNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            while (!randomNumbers.Add(value = random.Next(100, 999)));
            values.Add(value);
            values.Add(value);
        }
        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want something like this:

```
var list2 = new List<int>(list1.Count * 2);
foreach (var n in list1)
{
    list2.Add(n);
    list2.Add(n);
}
```

That will loop through the list and put each value into the second list twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your function as follows:

```
public static List<int> GetRandomNumbers(int count)
{
    List<int> Result = new List<int>();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int NewNumber = random.Next(100, 999);

        Result.Add(NewNumber);
        Result.Add(NewNumber);
    }

    return Result;
}
```

I tried the function above, it worked just like you said.